# Keep anchors & aliases on load/dump YAML using ruamel.yaml

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

How can I avoid `ruamel.yaml` from merging anchors when using yaml.load?
I would like to keep file as is, just modify some keys such as `production -> host` & `production -> port` and dump to file

```
defaults: &defaults
  host: <%= ENV.fetch("VBOX_IP", "127.0.0.1") %>
  adapter: mysql2
  reconnect: true
  encoding: utf8
  username: root

production:
  default:
    <<: *defaults
    host: dbname.domain.com
    port: 3306
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have that YAML example in file `config.yaml` then you can do:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()

with open('config.yaml') as ifp:
    data = yaml.load(ifp)
data['defaults']['reconnect'] = False
data['production']['default']['port'] += 1

with open('config.yaml', 'w') as ofp:
    yaml.dump(data, ofp)
```

to get an updated file:

```
defaults: &defaults
  host: <%= ENV.fetch("VBOX_IP", "127.0.0.1") %>
  adapter: mysql2
  reconnect: false
  encoding: utf8
  username: root

production:
  default:
    <<: *defaults
    host: dbname.domain.com
    port: 3307
```

The default `YAML()` (equivalent to `YAML(typ='rt')`) will get you the round-trip loader/dumper that preserves both the anchor name and the merge key (`<<`).

Please note that if you would do:

```
data['production']['default']['reconnect'] = 'False'
```

then the `reconnect` key would be added to the mapping that starts with the merge key.

Comment: Thanks for you detailed answer. i found a bug in my script that set any attribute which cause unwanted result